# Mysql service not started on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, service

MySql Server service not started.
[image: Please find screen shot for error message]

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.6/en/windows-start-service.html

did you checked this link. i had the same issue. i solved using this link.

Answer (score 0):

usually, this happens because the port for MySQL (probably 3306) is used by some other program. The most common case is Skype software. Skype uses the port 
3306, So if you have skype stop it first (end process from task manager, not just closing it). If you have no skype then check for other programs that might be using MySQL port for internet access. Stop that process then try starting MySQL again

Hope it helps